# How to replace image of a picture shape in PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

Is there any way to replace the image of an existing picture shape in PowerPoint from code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a linked image, either overwrite the linked image file with a new file or point the link at a new file.

Or if the shape is picture filled, you can fill it with a different picture instead.  That can distort the picture if its proportions don't match the shape's proportions; instead, you can change the aspect ratio of the shape to match that of the picture if need be.

To change the picture fill, assuming a reference to the shape in osh:

```
With osh.Fill
    .UserPicture ("C:\path\to\picture.jpg")
End With
```

To work out the size of the picture so you can adjust the shape to it, you can either use external image processing software or insert the picture into PPT, giving -1 for height and width parameters and pick up the .Height and .Width of the newly inserted picture, then delete it.

Or insert a new picture, pick up the old picture's size/position/other proprties and apply them to the new picture, delete the old picture, move the new one to the old one's Z-order.

Comment: Or if the shape is picture filled, you can fill it with a different picture instead.  
>> how can you do it in code?