# How can I change the bitmap in a PPT picture?

Tags: powerpoint, office-interop

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022620/how-to-replace-image-of-a-picture-shape-in-powerpoint) doesn't replace the bitmap, it adds to it. Is there a way to replace the bitmap in a picture?

Using PowerPoint COM interop (not VSTO).

The code is:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Create or update a picture (bitmap) tag.
        /// </summary>
        private static PowerPointTagLocation CreateOrUpdatePictureTag(PowerPointTagLocation tagLoc, bool isUpdate, Image picture,
            string text, Slide slide)
        {

            // get a unique name for the picture
            string name = FileUtils.MakeValidFileName("wr_bitmap", true) + rand.Next(9999);
            // we need a physical file as the bitmap to display.
            string filename = name + ".png";
            filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), filename);
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Trap.trap();
                File.Delete(filename);
            }

            // if it's an update for a picture, we just update the AlternativeText.
            // And the bitmap if we get it.
            if (isUpdate && tagLoc.IsPicture) {
                tagLoc.TagShape.AlternativeText = text;
                if (picture != null) {
                    picture.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
                    tagLoc.TagShape.Fill.UserPicture(filename);
                    File.Delete(filename);
                }
                return tagLoc;
            }

            if (picture == null)
                CommonBitmaps.photo_scenery.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);
            else
                picture.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);

            Shape shape;
            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filename)) {
                PictHandler.GetPictureSize(tagLoc.Tag, bitmap, 0, out var width, out var height);

                // position/extent in points. Place in middle of slide
                float x, y;
                try
                {
                    PageSetup page = ((Presentation)slide.Parent).PageSetup;
                    x = (page.SlideWidth - (width / 20f)) / 2f;
                    y = (page.SlideHeight - (height / 20f)) / 2f;

                }
                catch (Exception) {
                    x = y = 0;
                }
                shape = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(filename, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue, x, y, width / 20f, height / 20f);
                // set select
                shape.AlternativeText = text;
                shape.Name = name;
            }

            // copy properties across
//          if (copyPicture)
//              pic.AssignProperties(tagLoc.TagRange.Picture);
            // delete the old picture as we wrote a new one.
            if (isUpdate)
                tagLoc.Delete();

            // delete the temp file
            File.Delete(filename);

            return new PowerPointTagLocation(tagLoc.Tag, shape);
        }
```

Comment: The answer you've linked to *should* replace an existing picture on a slide, not add to it. It might help understand the problem you're seeing if you post your code.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - I've added the code. Please let me know if anything is unclear. thanks - dave

Comment: It looks to me like your code is adding a new picture rather than changing the picture fill of an existing shape (as in the code you linked to above) ... see shape = slide.Shapes.AddPicture

Comment: @SteveRindsberg if "isUpdate == true" then it is calling: tagLoc.TagShape.Fill.UserPicture(filename); Isn't that supposed to overwrite the bitmap? 

(for "isUpdate == false" yes then it creates a new picture.)

Comment: Thanks; I'm a VB/VBA user so not familiar with the syntax here. But yes, UserPicture(Filename) should fill the shape with the filename called for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this in as a support ticket to Microsoft and the answer I finally got back was you cannot replace the picture.